# Class that implements custom max function

Tags: python, max, point

I have two Point objects and the code looks like this:

```py
class Point:
    def __init__(self, x, y):
        self.x = x
        self.y = y

a = Point(1, 3)
b = Point(4, 2)
max(a, b) # Make this output Point(4, 3)
```

My question is: "How can I implement a custom [`max`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#max) function for the Point class that will return `Point(max(self.x, other.x), max(self.y, other.y))`?" The max function seems to just look at the [`__lt__`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/operator.html#operator.lt) and return the highest.

Comment: `def max(self, other): return Point(max(self.x, other.x), max(self.y, other.y))` ?

Comment: `max(a, b)` can return `a` or `b` - it can't generate new point with different values.

Comment: @furas Ok, that's too bad. So it's a limitation of Python?

Comment: Is there any specific reason to use `max` for it?

Comment: @furas: at least the built in `max`. one could write a new `max` just like you suggested in your first comment but not tied to the `Point` class. I wouldn't recommend this, though

Comment: Is this limited to just two points each time? Or to 2 *or more* points?

Comment: I will not use more than 2, but it's nice to have the option

Comment: @bereal that's the build in function so that would be the most logical function to "overload"

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`max()` *can't do this*, it can only return one of the elements given as input, *not* produce new instances.

You need to implement your own function:

```
def max_xy_point(*points):
    if not points:
        raise ValueError("Need at least 2 points to compare")
    if len(points) == 1:
        points = points[0]
    return Point(
        max(p.x for p in points),
        max(p.y for p in points)
    )
```

Like the built-in `max()` function, this can take either a single sequence (`max([p1, p2, p3, ...])` or separate arguments (`max(p1, p2, p3, ...)`).

Answer (score 4):

`max(a, b)` can return only `a` or `b` - it can't create point with new values.

You may add own method to class and use

```
c = a.max(b)
```

---

```
class Point:
    def __init__(self, x, y):
        self.x = x
        self.y = y

    def max(self, other):
        return Point(max(self.x, other.x), max(self.y, other.y))

a = Point(1, 3)
b = Point(4, 2)
c = a.max(b)
print(c.x, c.y)
```

Answer (score 2):

You can go about it like this, to get desired output:

```
class Point:

    def __init__(self, x, y):
        self.x = x
        self.y = y

    def max(self, other):
        if not isinstance(other, Point):
            return NotImplemented
        return Point(max(self.x, other.x), max(self.y, other.y))  

    def __repr__(self):
        return f'Point{self.x, self.y}'


a = Point(1, 3)
b = Point(4, 2)
a.max(b)
# Point(4, 3)
```